# keyboard event listener para validar un rango numérico

Tags: javascript, addkeylistener

Estoy tratando de validar un input que me va a pedir un código postal de 5 números. En este solo puedo ingresar un rango de números determinado. Si el valor introducido es menor que 28001 o mayor que 28071, entonces debe lanzarme un log que diga que no es válido y si es correcto, el log deberá decir que todo está bien. Lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

```
let cp = "";

document.getElementById('calc_shipping_postcode').addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  cp+= String.fromCharCode( e.key )
    if (cp.length === 5 ) {
      if(cp < 28001 || cp > 28071) {
        console.log("el código postal "+ cp + " no es válido");
      } else {
        console.log("código postal válido");
      }
    } 
});
```

El problema que tengo es que solo me lo valida la primera vez que inserto un valor. Yo lo que necesito es que cuando me diga "código postal NO válido", el listener siga comprobando las teclas que presiono, para que al corregir el código, lo vuelva a comprobar y me vuelva a decir si está bien o sigue estando mal.
También he probado a hacerlo con jquery pero no encuentro la forma de añadir el listener...

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es que siempre **añades** caracteres al string guardado en `cp`, por tanto sólo tendrá longitud 5 una vez. Podemos hacer algunos cambios en tu código para obtener directamente el valor del input:

```js
const cpInput = document.getElementById('calc_shipping_postcode');

// cambio el evento a keyup para que el input ya se haya actualizado
// con keydown aún tendríamos el valor previo al pulsado
cpInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  let cp = cpInput.value; //Si se han borrado caracteres, se verá reflejado
  console.log("cp vale",cp);
    if (cp.length === 5 ) {
      cp = +cp; //tranformamos a número
      if (cp < 28001 || cp > 28071) {
        console.log("el código postal "+ cp + " no es válido");
      } else {
        console.log("código postal válido");
      }
    } 
});
```

```html
<label>Zip Code</label> <input id="calc_shipping_postcode" />
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente!! muchísimas gracias por la aclaración!!